# Spring JPA OneToOne out of a OneToMany with only the fist entry

Tags: spring, jpa

my problem can be broken down to this little example:
I have a entity class A and a entity class B. A has a List of B objects. Now there is always only one B relevant. So I do not want to load all B's of an A, only to access this one B (last inserted B inside a A).
The question: Can I manipulate an entity without an service, so that there is a @Transient variable, that is always the newest B? And also without saving the newest B separately in A. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
class B{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private Date created = new Date();
}

class A{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany
    @OrderBy("created ASC")
    private List<B> b;

    @Transient
    private B newestB; // Here should be only the newest B
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Forget storing the newest B as a variable and instead simply add a getter for it:

```
@Transient
public B getNewestB() {
  return b.get(b.size() -1);
}
```

This will solve your problem under the assumption that `b` is set to `FetchType.EAGER`.  Fetching using `b`'s getter and `FetchType.LAZY` may not be so straight forward as Spring may rely on an AOP proxy call to trigger the lazy load (you'd need to experiment).

However, I'd discourage both these approaches.  You're effectively trying to fit business logic into your Entity.  Why not keep your entity clean and perform this query using B's repository?

E.g.

```
public interface BRepository extends CrudRepository<B, Long> {
  @Query(...)  //query to get newest B for specified A
  B getNewest(A a)
}
```